# How to get only a subset of data using graphql?

Tags: python, graphql

I have a lengthy query of the github API:

```py
query = """
{
  repository(name: "fifteen5", owner: "15five") {
    commit: object(expression: "c63a83caf81ef21616392fe5acb84f9655f94d92") {
      ... on Commit {
        associatedPullRequests(first:5){
          edges{
            node{
              title
              number
              body
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The returned value is a deepnly nested dictionary - to get the values I want (title, number, and body) I have to do something like this:

```py
# barf!
prs = areplStore['data']['repository']['commit']['associatedPullRequests']['edges']
for pr in prs:
    print(pr['node'])
```

The length of that dictionary access makes my eyes bleed. Is there something I can specify in my graphql query to return only the edges result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method that looks *slightly* cleaner is to use [py-jsonq](https://github.com/s1s1ty/py-jsonq). Unfortuantely this still has a lengthy access.

```py
from pyjsonq import JsonQ

j = JsonQ(data={'data': 
  {'repository': 
    {'commit': 
      {'associatedPullRequests': 
        {'edges': 
          [
            {'node': 
              {
                'title': 'Add more foobar', 
                'number': 14253,
                'body': 'More foo for the win'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
)

prs = [
  edge['node'] for edge in j.at('data.repository.commit.associatedPullRequests.edges').get()
]

print(prs)
```

https://repl.it/@almenon/json-q-test